# How do i create a pictureBox user control?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is what i did in the User Control code:
I added a User Control to my project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace Find_Distance
{
    public partial class pictureBox1Control : UserControl
    {
        public pictureBox1Control()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
            ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
            ControlStyles.UserPaint |
            ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

        }

        private readonly List<Ellipse> _clouds = new List<Ellipse>();
        public List<Ellipse> Clouds
        {
            get { return _clouds; }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

            foreach (var cloud in _clouds)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(
                   cloud.Brush, cloud.Center.X, cloud.Center.Y,
                   cloud.Diameter, cloud.Diameter);
            }

            base.OnPaint(e);
        }


        private void pictureBox1Control_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But when im using it in form1 for example:

```
pictureBox1Control.Image
```

The Image property is not exist.
I need to use this control as regular pictureBox1 and also as for other things.

EDIT**

Added paint event to the pictureBox:

```
pictureBox1 = new pictureBox1Control();
pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);
```

But its never get to the paint event:

```
 private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)  
 {
     e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
     e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
     e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
     e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, movingPoint);
     CloudEnteringAlert.Paint(e.Graphics, currentfactor, distance);   
 }
```

Why the event never fire ?

Comment: Your class doesn't have an Image property.  So *of course* you can't find it back in the Properties window or from IntelliSense.  Add an Image property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should inherit from PictureBox class. Declare your class as follows:

```
public partial class MyPictureBox : PictureBox
```

Then you can create an instance of this class and use the Image property (or use the designed to add that picturebox on the form):

```
MyPictureBox pictureBox1Control = new MyPictureBox();
pictureBox1Control.Image...
```

Comment: Cosmin where do i declare the MyPictureBox public partial class ? I declare it in the pictureBox1Control code ?

Comment: In the code that you wrote, you need to change this line: public partial class pictureBox1Control : UserControl  and instead of UserControl you shoul have PictureBox

Comment: Cosmin look at my edit now please im getting two errors on the User Control designer code.

Comment: Ok its now working no errors. But i don't see anything on the control. Nothis is draw. Do i need to add to the pictureBox events like paint ? And do i need to add also to the User Control designer pictureBox control ?

Comment: The PictureBox does not have AutoScaleMode and AutoScaleDimensions properties either. This are usually set on the container of a control, not on the control itself.

Comment: Edited my question now again last time. Please take a look.

Comment: You basically have a class named pictureBox1Control. You now need to add an instance of this class to a Form or to a UserControl. At runtime, when the Form or UserControl that contains your control is loaded (displayed) the event should be called. Try this in your main form, after initializecomponents() method: `pictureBox1Control c = new pictureBox1Control(); this.Controls.Add(c);`

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting from `UserControl` which does not have an `Image` property. To fix this, you can inherit from `PictureBox` or roll your own.